# What is this artifact and how to avoid it?

Tags: modeling

On a Sub.D cylinder(ngon "cap fill type"),i extruded the "cap" to make it round,then inset to flat it.When i apply a different color on the end part(as u see in the pic,sorry for my bad english)i found this artifact.

Only way i could fix was inset another face on it.But what it is and how to avoid it ? Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: I think it would be useful if you could share the file.

Comment: It's likely an artefact from subdividing the cap. You will notice similar ridges when subdividing a regular cylinder. You can combat this by adding another edge loop to the area where the materials are supposed to transition.

Comment: Thank you all !

Comment: I like your ship, :)

Comment: thx:) thats actually a metal gear rex im trying to do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of pattern that can arise in the transition between 'kite' quads and more regular quads under subdivision

[image]

If you can arrange for the transition to be inside a single-material region rather than at the boundary between materials, it doesn't show:

[image]

here, by <kbd>I</kbd> insetting the polar region

The [Catmull-Clark subdivision algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catmull%E2%80%93Clark_subdivision_surface) drags newly-created edge-points away from the previous concentrations at one side of a face.. this shows the transition between Simple and Catmull-Clark subdivision:

[image]

Comment: Didn't know about this issue or this fix +1

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!